# How to trigger animate() on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have skillbars with a background animation. It's just fine when the skillbars are initially visible but when I've to trigger the button for making the skillbars visible, the animation doesn't seem to work. Actually it works but just I push an another button.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english !

Here's my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mnvfdkf4/2/
Bootstrap doc: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary collapse-control" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseLangages" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseLangages">Langages</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary collapse-control" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFrameworks" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFrameworks">Frameworks</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary collapse-control" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseCMS" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCMS">CMS</a>

<div class="collapse in" id="collapseLangages">
    <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="90%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #E34F26<span>HTML5</span></div>
        <div class="skillbar-container">
            <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e67e22;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">90%</div>
    </div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->
    <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="90%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2980b9;"<span>CSS3</span></div>
        <div class="skillbar-container">
            <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #3498db;"></div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
  function animateSkillbar(){
    $('.in .skillbar').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:$(this).attr('data-percent')
        },5000);
    });     
}
animateSkillbar();

$( ".collapse-control" ).on( "click", function() {
    animateSkillbar();
});
```

Comment: Try not to post a block of code and make a small, reproducible example of your issue. Anything over 50 lines, especially your whole program, is hard for others to debug.

Comment: As the width is set it doesn't animate. Change the width to 0 and animate

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh It should be better now. :) And the width is already defined to 0 in css (line 56 on fiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after clicking class `in` is not already set. So you need catch [`shown.bs.collapse`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) event when collapse element has been made visible to the user:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  animateSkillbar();
})
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/0qa3u3wu/ ]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Replace the Javascript

```
 function animateSkillbar(){  
    $('.in .skillbar').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').attr("width",0))
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:$(this).attr('data-percent')
        },1000);
    });     
}
animateSkillbar();

$( ".collapse-control" ).on( "click", function() {
$('.in .skillbar-bar').each(function(b){

 console.log($('.in .skillbar-bar').eq(b)[0].style.width = 0)
})
   animateSkillbar();
});
```